# how to create singleton instance per thread using MEF

Tags: mef

I am new in MEF. I am working on a C# WPF application and using Prism with MEF.

Please tell me how can I create single instance per thread of a class using MEF.

Thanka a lot
DJ

Comment: redefine the problem. (MEF is for _extensibility_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of MEF, you would need to develop a complex hierarchy of containers in order to accomodate this requirement (singleton per thread).  Since you are new to MEF, this would be quite tricky to implement.  Here is a link with more information about this:

http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2009/08/16/should-i-use-mef-for-my-general-ioc-needs/

I believe one of the new options in the new version of MEF (currently called MEF2) will be better options for how to handle object instantiation.  You can read more about it at the BCL blog or here:

http://mef.codeplex.com/